# Проблема с проходом массива по условию

Tags: c++, массивы

Добрый день. Пытаюсь написать простую программу которая будет из исходного текста подставлять другие значения.
Проблема в том, что программа заменяет значения только первых пяти элементов и то, если они написаны слитно без знаков препинания, добавление латинских букв к примеру вообще крашит программу.
Я пробовал увеличить значение переменной которая отвечает за замену элементов, но проблема решается 50 на 50. Крашится так же. Только строка из слитных букв больше.
Исходный код ниже. Так же выложу весь проект. Может так проще будет.
https://yadi.sk/d/nGIOLDqB35vc7y

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include"resource.h"

HWND hEdit1;
HWND hEdit2;

const int m = 1000, n = 5;

CHAR str[m] = { 0 };
CHAR rezult[] = { 0 };

CHAR buttons[n] = { 'X','Y','A','B' };




BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR     lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

DialogBoxParam(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), 0, (DlgProc), 0);

return 0;
}

BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (uMsg) {
case WM_INITDIALOG: {

    hEdit1 = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1);
    SetWindowText(hEdit1, str);
    SetFocus(hEdit1);

    hEdit2 = GetDlgItem(hwnd,IDC_EDIT2);
    SetWindowText(hEdit2, rezult);
    break;
}
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case IDC_BUTTON1:

        GetWindowText(hEdit1, str, 255);

        for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
        if (str[i] > '0' && str[i] < m + '0')
            {
                str[i] = buttons[str[i] - '0' - 1];
            }

        SetWindowText(hEdit2, str);
        break;
    case IDOK:
        MessageBox(hwnd, "OK", "Info", MB_OK || MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        break;
    case IDCANCEL:
        EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
        return FALSE;
    }
    break;
case WM_CLOSE:
    EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
    return FALSE;
}
return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Что это такое  m + '0' ?

Comment: Насколько я знаю массив вроде с 0 начинает отсчет.
А мне надо 
1 = X, 2 = Y, 3 = A, 4 = B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данный цикл

```
    for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
    if (str[i] > '0' && str[i] < m + '0')
        {
            str[i] = buttons[str[i] - '0' - 1];
        }
```

не имеет никакого смысла. Так как переменная `m` имеет значение равное 1000

```
const int m = 1000, n = 5;
          ^^^^^^^^
```

то, фактически, данное условие

```
if (str[i] > '0' && str[i] < m + '0')
```

будет выполнено для любого значения `str[i]`, большего `'0'`. Однако корректный диапазон индексов для массив `buttons` , объявленного как

```
CHAR buttons[n] = { 'X','Y','A','B' };
```

это всего лишь `[0, 3]` . Таким образом для любого значения `str[i]`, которое больше `'4'` будет иметь место выход за пределы массива, что ведет к неопределенному поведению программы.

Comment: Получается нужно убрать ограничение на сам массив?
Или просто исключить лишнюю переменную из программы?

Comment: @Petr Во-первых, у вас цикл от 0 до 4 for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i), поэтому только 5 начальных символа строки проверяются. А, во-вторых, вам надо гарантировать, что индекс в массиве buttons не выйдет за его пределы.

Comment: Странно. Я применил точно такой же массив в программе в консольном виде и там все прекрасно работало.
Спасибо за подсказку. Буду дальше мучать код:)

Comment: @Petr Имейте в виду, что, возможно, у вас включен UNICODE, а потому вы должны иметь дело с "широкими" символами.

Comment: В настройках проекта стоит использование многобайтовой кодировки.

Comment: @Petr Тогда вам символьные литералы нужно заключать в макросы Windows, я уже не помню, какие они там, но что-то вроде _T или еще как-то там.